# jquery dialog box debugging with firebug

Tags: jquery, debugging, firebug

once jQuery dialog box comes up, none of the breakpoints work in firebug.

any ideas?

Comment: Where are your break points at? Are they in the callback functions for the buttons or do you have buttons on the dialog? Are they elsewhere in the page? Did you try refreshing the page?

Comment: my dialog box, has several fields which are validated using jquery. It also makes ajax calls. breakpoint works only for the javascript on the page itself, but nor for the modal dialog box which has comeup on top of the page.

Comment: Is everything working like it should? Validation and the ajax calls? If not then look over the javascript code and see if there are any typos or anything. If something is wrong with the code or something tries to access a null value then the code will generally just crap out on you. Set a break point at the start of page load and step through it line by line. When the modal dialog comes up it should continue to debug whenever a line of code needs to be executed without a breakpoint. Just remember not to hit F8 or the continue/play button in firebug.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dropdown menu where you can select your javascript file. normally the js files gets replaced with html file when using dialog box we have to manually change it to you js file. hope it works:)